# Harmonic gauge condition in Fourier space

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, fourier-transform, perturbation-theory, gauge

I am currently working through Sean Carroll's notes on general relativity, specifically the weak fields and gravitational radiation section*.

When discussing gravitational radiation emitted by an isolated source, we Fourier transform the trace reversed metric perturbation to give (after various approximations - eqn 6.78):

$$\tilde{\bar{h}}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, x) = 4G \frac{e^{i \omega R}}{R}\int d^3 y \ \tilde{T}_{\mu \nu}(\omega, y) \tag{1}.$$

Sean then goes onto argue that we do not need to compute all the components of the perturbation, since the harmonic gauge condition $\partial_{\mu}\bar{h}^{\mu \nu}(t, x) = 0$ in Fourier space implies

$$\tilde{\bar{h}}^{0 \nu} = \frac{i}{\omega}\partial_i \tilde{\bar{h}}^{i \nu} \tag{2}.$$

However, even via direct substitution of (1) into (2) I cannot see why this is the case. Furthermore, I am unsure how the Harmonic gauge condition transforms under the Fourier transformation. Please, why does (2) follow from this?

*For reference - https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll6.html

Comment: A similar argument is used on equation (6.81), where a Fourier transform of the energy-momentum conservation equation is considered.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify: are you asking how to Fourier transform harmonic gauge condition, how the transformed gauge condition implies that computing all the components of the perturbation is unnecessary, or both?

Comment: Just how to Fourier transform the gauge condition, as it is clear to me from (2) why computing all components would be unnecessary. Thanks.

Comment: What does a Fourier transform do to time derivatives? ...